# QuickBooks Web Connector - Can't find SOAP response

Tags: soap, quickbooks

I'm trying to build a SOAP server to interact with the QuickBooks Web Connector, but can't find any examples of what the SOAP response to it's request to `authenticate` should be.

How do we respond to this?

I tried to find a way to response this action, but there is no document or example.

`{'soapaction': '"http://developer.intuit.com/authenticate"', 'host': 'api:3000', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)', 'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'cookie': None, 'content-length': '382', 'ssl-client-verify': 'NONE', 'x-forwarded-for': '12.34.567.89', 'x-real-ip': '12.34.567.89', 'anvil-host': 'Jeremiah.QB.app'}`

Answer (score 1):

### WSDL

You can find a `WSDL` for this service at the link below, which may help you develop:

- https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl

### Example SOAP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <authenticate xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/">
            <strUserName xsi:type="xsd:string">username</strUserName>
            <strPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">password</strPassword>
        </authenticate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

#### Example SOAP response *for a VALID* login

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 May 2009 17:45:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.7l DAV/2 PHP/5.2.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Content-Length: 416
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:authenticateResponse>
            <ns1:authenticateResult>
                <ns1:string>15c9ce293bd3f41b761c21635b14fa06</ns1:string>
                <ns1:string></ns1:string>
            </ns1:authenticateResult>
        </ns1:authenticateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### Example SOAP response *for an INVALID* login

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 May 2009 17:43:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.7l DAV/2 PHP/5.2.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Content-Length: 387
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:authenticateResponse>
            <ns1:authenticateResult>
                <ns1:string></ns1:string>
                <ns1:string>nvu</ns1:string>
            </ns1:authenticateResult>
        </ns1:authenticateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Source:

- `authenticate`:  http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector_soap_authenticate
- all of the other Web Connector SOAP methods: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#array_authenticate_string_strusername_string_strpassword